# Algorithm which check if in arrays S and T are integers s and t so s+t=k if k is given number

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am trying to make algorithm that takes two arrays, S and T of n integers and integer k. The algorithm checks whether the arrays have integers s and t so s+t=k.( s in S and t in T.) The algorithm is supposed to have run time of O(n log n).

Have tried to think of something that sort array T and use for loop to go through S and use binary search to see if I find integer like k - S[i] for every element in S. But that will always have running time greater than n log n, i think.

Not looking for someone to write the code. Only asking here to get some ideas.

Comment: If the integers in S and T are bounded in a range of size m, you could devise a O(n) algorithm with space complexity O(m).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort the two lists, this is O(n log n).

Then set up two iterators. One iterator starts at the *lowest* value in S and goes forward through ever-increasing values in S. The other iterator starts at the *highest* value in T and iterates through ever-decreasing values.

Repeat the following:

- if the current values sum to a number greater than *k*, advance the T iterator. This should decrease the sum.
- if the current values sum to a number less than *k*, advance the S iterator. This should increase the sum.
- if the current values sum to *k*, then exit with success.

This second phase should cause, at most, 2N advances, and hence is O(n). So the total complexity is O(n log n).

This has the same complexity as repeated binary search, but this algorithm should be faster, especially for large *n*.

Answer (score 3):

Sort *both* the arrays. Step through them in *opposite* directions. If the sum of the two elements is smaller than k advance the "increasing" pointer, if it is larger than k, step the decreasing pointer. This method may be a bit slower than sorting only one of the arrays, but the final pass is definitely faster. And probably shorter, because the head and tail-part of the two arrays can be skipped (pruned away).

Comment: And no need to binary search, hooray!

Comment: It is the same as Aaron McDaid's. But he beat me on time.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm that you've specified actually does have runtime O(n log n), assuming that the total number of elements in both arrays is O(n).  You can see this here:

- Sort one of the arrays (O(n log n))
- For each element of the other array: (O(n) iterations)

  - Do a binary search to see if the complementary element is in the other array (O(log n) time)

The first step takes time O(n log n), and the second step consists of O(n) iterations of an O(log n) algorithm, which thus also takes time O(n log n).  Since O(n log n) + O(n log n) = O(n log n), your algorithm runs in time O(n log n).  So it looks like you've got exactly the algorithm you're looking for!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems correct; first sorting the arrays, two O(n log n) operations, and then you perform n binary searches, which are O(log n) each.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting is O(n log n). Then, for each O(n) first elements, you have an O(log n) search for a matching element. That sounds like O(n log n) in total (since O(f) + O(f) = O(f) for any function f).

Answer (score 0):

Yet another method: store one of the arrays in a hashtable (O(N)). Do a linear pass through the other (O(N)) and for every elem do a lookup for `k-elem` in the hashtable. Total runtime: 2*O(N) := O(N). Profit!